# How to make my Main Menu buttons to work in my Game

Tags: java, lwjgl

I'm trying to make main menu for my game and I dont know how to make my buttons to work.
I'm using `Slic2D` and `LWJGL` libraries

My GameMenu Class:

```
package lt.CobaltPlanet.nelixus.state;

import org.newdawn.slick.*;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.*;



public class GameMenu extends BasicGameState{

    Image Backgruond,Game_Title;
    Image play,play_hover,play_pressed;
    Image option,option_hover,option_pressed;
    Image quit,quit_hover,quit_pressed;

    public GameMenu(int state){
    }

    public void init(GameContainer gamecontainer1, StateBasedGame statebasedgame1) throws SlickException{
    Game_Title = new Image("res/Game_Title.png");
    Backgruond = new Image("res/BG.png");
    play = new Image("res/Main_menu_buttons/play.png");
    play_hover = new Image("res/Main_menu_buttons/play_hover.png");
    play_pressed = new Image("res/Main_menu_buttons/play_pressed.png");
    quit = new Image("res/Main_menu_buttons/quit.png");
    quit_hover = new Image("res/Main_menu_buttons/quit_hover.png");
    quit_pressed = new Image("res/Main_menu_buttons/quit_pressed.png");
    option = new Image("res/Main_menu_buttons/options.png");
    option_hover = new Image("res/Main_menu_buttons/options_hover.png");
    option_pressed = new Image("res/Main_menu_buttons/options_pressed.png");
    }

    public void render(GameContainer gamecontainer1, StateBasedGame statebasedgame1, Graphics g1) throws SlickException{
            Backgruond.draw(0,0);
            play.draw(205,206);
            option.draw(205,286);
            quit.draw(205, 366);
            Game_Title.draw(0,-100);
            //Mouse Position
            g1.drawString(mousePos, 10, 25);
        }


    public void update(GameContainer gamecontainer1, StateBasedGame statebasedgame1, int delta1) throws SlickException{ 
    }
    public int getID(){
        return 1;
    }

}
```

Comment: What specifically isn't working?

Comment: i need to test when player pressing button or no any help?

Comment: Pleas help me to make buttons working:)

Comment: does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18165812/slick-button-will-not-work) not help?

Comment: i dont understand how to set possition :
`if( (xpos > 683) && (xpos < 920) && (ypos > 440) && (ypos < 478) ) {`

Comment: any help how to set pos?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](http://legacy.lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/input/Mouse.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752725/finding-whether-a-point-lies-inside-a-rectangle-or-not). You want the mouse position:

```
int mousePosX = Mouse.getX();
int mousePosY = Mouse.getY();
```

And check whether the mouse was clicked:

```
Mouse.isButtonDown(0);
```

The use Slick's `Rectangle.contains(float x, float y)` to see if the point is in the hitbox for your button. Let's assume you have a button with a Slick rectangle set up:

```
if(Mouse.isButtonDown(0) && buttonHitbox.contains(mousePosX, mousePosY)) {
    System.out.println("The button was clicked!");
}
```

**Update:**

```
if(quitRect.contains(Mouse.getX(), Mouse.getY()) {
    //draw hover image
    quit_hover.draw();
    //check if button is pressed
    if(Mouse.isButtonDown(0)) {
        System.out.println("Button pressed");
    }
}
```

This also draws the hover image.

**Update II:**

```
package lt.CobaltPlanet.nelixus.state;

import org.newdawn.slick.*;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.*;
import org.newdawn.slick.geom.*;


public class GameMenu extends BasicGameState{

    boolean playHover = false;
    Rectangle playRect;
    Image Backgruond,Game_Title;
    Image play,play_hover,play_pressed;
    Image option,option_hover,option_pressed;
    Image quit,quit_hover,quit_pressed;

    public GameMenu(int state){
    }

    public void init(GameContainer gamecontainer1, StateBasedGame statebasedgame1) throws SlickException{
    Game_Title = new Image("res/Game_Title.png");
    Backgruond = new Image("res/BG.png");
    play = new Image("res/Main_menu_buttons/play.png");
    playRect = new Rectangle(205, 206, play.getWidth(), play.getHeight());
    play_hover = new Image("res/Main_menu_buttons/play_hover.png");
    play_pressed = new Image("res/Main_menu_buttons/play_pressed.png");
    quit = new Image("res/Main_menu_buttons/quit.png");
    quit_hover = new Image("res/Main_menu_buttons/quit_hover.png");
    quit_pressed = new Image("res/Main_menu_buttons/quit_pressed.png");
    option = new Image("res/Main_menu_buttons/options.png");
    option_hover = new Image("res/Main_menu_buttons/options_hover.png");
    option_pressed = new Image("res/Main_menu_buttons/options_pressed.png");
    }

    public void render(GameContainer gamecontainer1, StateBasedGame statebasedgame1, Graphics g1) throws SlickException{
            Backgruond.draw(0,0);
            play.draw(205,206);
            option.draw(205,286);
            quit.draw(205, 366);
            if(playHover) play_hover.draw(205, 206);
            Game_Title.draw(0,-100);
            //Mouse Position
            g1.drawString(mousePos, 10, 25);
        }


    public void update(GameContainer gamecontainer1, StateBasedGame statebasedgame1, int delta1) throws SlickException{ 
        playHover = false;
        if(playRect.contains(Mouse.getX(), Mouse.getY()) {
            playHover = true;
            if(Mouse.isbuttonDown(0)) {
                System.out.println("The button was pressed!");
            }
        }
    }
    public int getID(){
        return 1;
    }

}
```

This is your code, I added the functionality for the play button. Now you should be able to do the rest by yourself.

Comment: ohh i have custom buttons

Comment: What do you mean, custom buttons? I saw that you are using images.

Comment: i using images as button

Comment: Yes, at you are drawing them at certain positions, right? Now for every image, you create a rectangle instance with the same position/size that they're drawn at. Then, for every button rectangle you do the check I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: yeas but i dont know how to set pos `if( (xpos > 683) && (xpos < 920) && (ypos > 440) && (ypos < 478) )`

Comment: What do you mean? Look at my answer, I'm telling you how to get the mouse position, check if there is a mouse click and in this comment, told you that you need to create a rectangle for every button. The rectangle is what you use as a hitbox for the button. You do NOT need the code you took from the link in my comment on your question. Remove that code. You only need what's in my answer.

Comment: its works i think but if i press on whe screen not button works too or not??

Comment: Please make ab edit to your question and add the code you have now. I'll look at the problem then.

Comment: Please update the code in your question so I can look at your new code.

Comment: i can't update code for one reason:
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Comment: i just added `public void update(GameContainer gamecontainer1, StateBasedGame statebasedgame1, int delta1) throws SlickException{ 
  int posX = Mouse.getX();
  int posY = Mouse.getY();
  
  if(Mouse.isButtonDown(0) && buttonHitbox.contains(posX, posY)) {
      System.out.println("The button was clicked!");
  }
 }`

Comment: In the constructor, you need to create a rectangle instance. For example for play: playRect = new Rectangle(205, 206, imageWidth, imageHeight);

Comment: in which public i need to create `playRect = new Rectangle(205, 206, imageWidth, imageHeight);`

Comment: I have updated my answer with your code but added play functionality. Check it out.

Comment: Please post another question for that, maybe somebody else can help.

Comment: i think i need if statment for buttons

Comment: For example:
`if( (xpos > 683) && (xpos < 920) && (ypos > 440) && (ypos < 478) ) {

        if(Mouse.isButtonDown(0)) {

            sbg.enterState(1);

        }`
but i don't know how to get posx and posy

Comment: You don't need that. playRect are the coordinates for the play button.

Comment: yeah i know but when i pressing play button it's dosent work but if u press in center of option button it's works as play

Comment: maybe i need draw image for example:
PlayNow.draw(680, 320, 250, 50);

Comment: Why don't you just edit playRect's coordinates so that it fits?

Comment: i know but how to get coordinates of play button?

Comment: Look at your code: you call play.draw(205, 206) Now look at playRect: i say 205, 206, play.getWidth(), play.getHeight().

Comment: Then use 205, 100. Seriously, just try a few values. I can't help you any more than that and I can't just write all code for you. If I helped you, please accept my answer. You are on the right track now.

Comment: it's was  playRect = new Rectangle(205, 300, play.getWidth(), play.getHeight());

Comment: I'm glad I could help. I advise you to read tutorials on this topic, though.

Comment: but maybe can u help litle bit more?

Comment: You need to ask another question for that. I will meet you there.

Comment: but question is how to add one more button?:D

Comment: Add another boolean, another rectangle and make another if statement. That's it. Do what I did. There is seriously nothing else.

Comment: i asked new question pleas help:)